# jbpm Error while creating JAXB Marshaller due to 580 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, jbpm

I am getting an error while I add external jars in `JBPM KIE Work Bench` and while I try to create a process. If I don't add the external jars, everything is working fine.

> 2019-08-30 21:19:37,718 ERROR [org.kie.server.api.marshalling.jaxb.JaxbMarshaller] (default task-9) Error while creating JAXB Marshaller due to 580 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 580 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
>   org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2 is a non-static inner class, and JAXB can't handle those.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2
>   org.apache.activemq.filter.Expression is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at org.apache.activemq.filter.Expression
>           at public org.apache.activemq.filter.Expression org.apache.activemq.filter.BinaryExpression.getLeft()
>           at org.apache.activemq.filter.BinaryExpression
>           at org.apache.activemq.filter.LogicExpression
>           at org.apache.activemq.filter.LogicExpression$2
>   Two classes have the same XML type name "". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2
>       this problem is related to the following location:
>           at org.apache.activemq.filter.LogicExpression$2
>   Two classes have the same XML type name "baseDataStreamMarshaller". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.

I am using `JBPM 7.8.0`

Comment: Hi, Was this issue resolved? If yes, how?